# This request is not authorized to perform this operation while trying to read a blob from Data Lake gen2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake-gen2

I would like to copy a blob from one Datalake to another one, here is my simple code to do this job:

```
    DataLakeFileSystemClient sourceDataLakeFileSystemClient = StorageAccountDataLakeHelper.GetDataLakeFileSystemClient(SourceContainer, SOURCE_DATALAKE_NAME, SOURCE_DATA_LAKE_ACCESS_KEY);
    DataLakeFileSystemClient taregetDataLakeFileSystemClient = StorageAccountDataLakeHelper.GetDataLakeFileSystemClient(TargetContainer, TARGET_DATALAKE_NAME, TARTGET_DATA_LAKE_ACCESS_KEY);
    DataLakeDirectoryClient sourcedirectoryClient = sourceDataLakeFileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("folder1/folder2/");
    DataLakeFileClient sourcefileClient = sourcedirectoryClient.GetFileClient("myfile.csv.csv");    
    Stream reader= await sourcefileClient.OpenReadAsync();
    DataLakeDirectoryClient targetdirectoryClient = taregetDataLakeFileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("folder1/folder2/");
    DataLakeFileClient targetfileClient = await targetdirectoryClient.CreateFileAsync("myfile.csv.csv");
```

The authentication based on access key as you can see. I can run this code localy successfully. but if I publishe to a function app in azure I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Azure.RequestFailedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Service request failed.
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Headers:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 0d261530-201e-009b-5a39-3c8d7e000000
x-ms-client-request-id: 13ec55f9-7a99-4959-bb1c-024e5848a414
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationFailure
Date: Wed, 28 Apr 2021 14:20:59 GMT
```

Exception occures on this line:

```
Stream reader= await sourcefileClient.OpenReadAsync();
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: One possibility are the keys are out of date.  Check the certificate and see expiration date.

Comment: I am using Primary key and not SAS key and as I said I can run it localy on my machine

Comment: Are you connecting to same server/database local and remote.  When you work do you get same headers?  When you make a HTTP connection there is a negotiation that occurs between client and server using the headers to get common transfer mode.  The server may only accept HTTP 2.0 and when you are running locally you may be using HTTP 1.0 or 1.1.  The webpage you are connecting has heads and your request also has headers.  When a header is not sent a default mode is used.  So you may be able to solve issue by adding headers to your request.  Your client may not work with http 2.0.

Comment: I  am using Private Endpoint to connect to Source DataLake. On the Source DataLake If I say Allow all Network, then I don't receive this exception. But I would like to communicate with my Source DataLake with Private Endpoint. Could it be the reason? what I dont understand why it works localy

Comment: When your client is connecting to a remote server, the server has to be configured to accept the clients credentials.  The server under good conditions will send back a 200 OK with valid data in the body.   Under bad conditions the server will return a 400/500 error and no data in the body.  Your response has headers by no body so you get an exception when you try to read a null body.  See Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: Hi, any update? Can my answer helps you? :)

Answer (score 1):

I use below code and deploy to azure, it seems work fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;

namespace FunctionApp110
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string sourcefs = "source";
            string sinkfs = "sink";
            string sourcedir = "test";
            string sinkdir = "test";
            string sourcefile = "source.txt";
            string sinkfile = "sink.txt";
            DataLakeFileSystemClient sourcefilesystemclient = new DataLakeFileSystemClient(str, sourcefs);
            DataLakeFileSystemClient sinkfilesystemclient = new DataLakeFileSystemClient(str, sinkfs);
            var sourcedirectoryclient = sourcefilesystemclient.GetDirectoryClient(sourcedir);
            var sinkdirectoryclient = sinkfilesystemclient.GetDirectoryClient(sinkdir);
            var sourcefileclient = sourcedirectoryclient.GetFileClient(sourcefile);
            Stream reader = sourcefileclient.OpenRead();
            MemoryStream msreader = new MemoryStream();
            reader.CopyTo(msreader);
            msreader.Position = 0;
            DataLakeFileClient sinkfileclient = sinkdirectoryclient.CreateFile(sinkfile);
            sinkfileclient.Append(msreader, 0);
            sinkfileclient.Flush(sourcefileclient.GetProperties().Value.ContentLength);
            return new OkObjectResult("This is a test.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it.:)